# Не могу выполнить функцию regex с номером телефона

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Выходит ошибка PHP Warning 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0'

При попытке сделать регулярное выражение

```
!preg_match("/+998944071425/m", '+998944071425');
```

В самом php коде выглядит так

```
if (!preg_match("/$phone_from/m", $user->phone))
```

Comment: Да откуда это извращение пихать регулярки вместо сравнения на равенство?

Comment: Не знаю откуда, сказали пофиксить баг, вижу такое 
Простое правило, работает не трогай

Comment: Есть еще правило бойскаута: «оставь место стоянки чище, чем оно было до твоего прихода»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте экранировать символ `+` (метасимвол, который зарезервирован):

`!preg_match("/\+998944071425/m", '+998944071425');`

В коде:

`if (!preg_match('/\\' . $phone_from . '/m', $user->phone))`

Тут 2 проблемы: символ `+` в значении и `$` в переменной. Нашел способ решить проблему через такую конкатенацию.

Comment: Большое спасибо, действительно проблема была в этом